# Retain function in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Have scenario where need to retain values based on condition.

1. Assign "Change date" on "AA start Date" then check for "Change in Duration".
2. If "change in Duration" < 60 then 1st Change date will be assigned till next Change in duration > 60
3. then retain new change date in "AA start date". Sample is given below.
4. "AA_START_DATE" is final column which I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Your sample data really has nothing to do with your explanation.  What is "change in duration"?  *Desired results* would really help.  As would a simpler presentation of data that removed unimportant columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this as follows: Any alternate way is appreciable

```
(select CIN,AA_CODE,EXT_AA_MESSAGE,CHG_DATE,EXP_DATE,PREV_CHG_DATE,CHG_DATE_DUR,AA_START_DTE,
  sum(case when AA_START_DTE is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by CIN,AA_CODE order by CHG_DATE) as value_partition from (select CIN,AA_CODE,EXT_AA_MESSAGE,CHG_DATE,EXP_DATE, 
  case when CIN_AA_CODE_FIRST = 1 then NULL else PREV_CHG_DATE end as PREV_CHG_DATE,
  case when  CIN_AA_CODE_FIRST <> 1 then date_diff(CHG_DATE,PREV_CHG_DATE,DAY) end as CHG_DATE_DUR,
  case when CIN_AA_CODE_FIRST = 1 or (case when CIN_AA_CODE_FIRST <> 1 then date_diff(CHG_DATE,PREV_CHG_DATE,DAY) end ) > 60 then CHG_DATE 
  end as AA_START_DTE,      
  from
 ( select CIN,AA_CODE,EXT_AA_MESSAGE,CHG_DATE,EXP_DATE, LAG(CHG_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CIN,AA_CODE ORDER BY CHG_DATE ASC) as PREV_CHG_DATE,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY CIN,AA_CODE ORDER BY CHG_DATE ASC) AS CIN_AA_CODE_FIRST from TABLE )))`
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is a type of gap and islands problem, where you want to remember the first date in sequence that is 60+ days from the previous date.

You can handle this by using `lag()` to get the previous date.  Then use a cumulative conditional maximum to get the time when the most recent change occurred:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when change_date > date_add(change_date, interval -60 day) then null else change_date
           end) over (partition by cn, aa_code
                      order by change_date
                      ) as aa_start_date
from (select t.*,
             lag(change_date) over (partition by cn, aa_code order by change_date) as prev_change_date
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: lag() return just previous one. but If you see , I want very first value in AA_START_DATE for many rows untill CHNG_DATE_DUR > 60.

Comment: @MdEkram . . . What is returned is the result of the `max()`, not the `lag()`.

Comment: Only first row is matching.